# Internationalization of fields errors

Tags: java, spring, internationalization, thymeleaf

I have successfully done this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/

My question is how to do internationalization on fields errors. I mean this line:

```
<td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="*{name}">Name Error</td>
```

Normaly  it is done by:

```
th:text="#{name}"
```

I was trying many ways, for example `"#{*name}"` and more, but it causes expression language processor to fail.

How this should be done in a proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my project I've done it this way :

1) In the view :

```
<div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('surname')}" 
     th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('surname')}">
    <span class="text-danger" th:text="${err}"></span><br/>
</div>
```

2) In the `message.properties` (localized error messages) :

> NotEmpty.personBean.surname = Surname is empty!
>     Size.personBean.surname = Surname must be from {2} up to {1} symbols!

In your case you must use name of your form's bean - `personForm` , for example :

> NotNull.personForm.name=Name must not be null!